# Mouse events for Picture box that is Created in a C# class

Tags: c#, class, picturebox

I am Creating a Chess.I added a Picture box on design form as Chessboard..then for each piece (for example horse or elephant and...) Added a Class.cs and created picture box for each piece in those classes.like this:

```
public class Mohre
{
   public Mohre()
   {

   }
   public void draw(Form form,PictureBox pic )
   {
       pic.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
       pic.Image = Chess1.Properties.Resources.sarbaz;
       pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
       pic.Visible = true;
       form.Controls.Add(pic);
       pic.BringToFront();

   }

}
```

&

```
public class Soldier:Mohre
{
   public PictureBox picsoldier = new PictureBox();

   public Soldier()
   {
       picsoldier.Left = 436;
       picsoldier.Top = 670;

   }
   public void movement()
   {

       picsoldier.Top -= 67;  

   }

}
```

(not add picture box on design form Directly.) now I want to when user click on the pieces that created in classesو movement function will be called.
what should I Do?

Comment: yes its a win form

Comment: are you attaching to the mousedown event in the picturebox of the piece? you know pic.mousedown += yourFunction

Comment: it doesn't work and shows Error Right side the +=

Comment: I didn't TAB when write your code..problem solved.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean this ?

```
lblname.Click += delegate { nameOfUrFunction (lblname); };

private void nameOfUrFunction (Label lbl)
{

}
```